# Django order many to many relationship

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have been playing around with Django's many to many field with the following models:

```
class ProjectLanguage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    main_text = models.TextField(default="main project description ...", null=True, blank=True)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(ProjectLanguage)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to get a list of projects ordered by their ProjectLanguage title.   How do I achieve this with Django ?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method like this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    def ordered_languages(self):
        return self.languages.all().order_by('title')
```

Or you may want to use a [through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) with [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#ordering).